# Reading a file into Verilog

Tags: file-io, verilog

I am trying to read a text file which contains integer numbers. I have this txt file in project folder. I am trying to use this code but it is getting char due to `$fgetc`. Now what I want do is that how can I get integers from text?

Here is code:

```
integer file;
reg [31:0] char;

begin 
  file=$fopen ("Links.txt","rb");
  char=$fgetc(file);
  $display("char=%d", char);
end
```

PS: This is my first time, I am reading any file.

Comment: [Related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16630319/97073)

Comment: @Morgan
It gives the error of "Syntax error near "signed". And if I remove sign it gives error "Logic is an unknown type".
So where might be I doing error?

Comment: They signed is part of verilog from 2001, logic is a SystemVerilog type. If you could edit the question and add what simulator your using etc that migt be helpful, sounds like your limited to verilog-95.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution was [posted previously using SystemVerilog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651509/97073), edited verion here for Verilog compatible syntax.

```
integer               data_file    ; // file handler
integer               scan_file    ; // file handler
reg [21:0] captured_data;
`define NULL 0    

initial begin
  data_file = $fopen("data_file.dat", "r");
  if (data_file == `NULL) begin
    $display("data_file handle was NULL");
    $finish;
  end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  scan_file = $fscanf(data_file, "%d\n", captured_data); 
  if (!$feof(data_file)) begin
    //use captured_data as you would any other wire or reg value;
  end
end
```